# SQL - order by column if value exists, otherwise second column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, multiple-columns

How to order SQL result by column `name` and if there is not set name, order it by `email`.

```
+----+-------+-----------------+
| ID | name  |      email      |
+----+-------+-----------------+
|  1 | John  | john@gmail.com  |
|  2 | ---   | linda@gmail.com |
|  3 | ---   | kikli@gmail.com |
|  4 | Peter | peter@gmail.com |
+----+-------+-----------------+
```

Result should looks like that:

```
John, kikli@gmail.com, linda@gmail.com, Peter
```

Answer:

```
$users = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('a.id, coalesce(concat(a.firstName, concat(\' \', a.lastName)), a.email) as orderColumn')
        ->from('Company\User\Admin', 'a')
        ->orderBy('orderColumn','ASC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getScalarResult();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select coalesce(lastName || ' ' || firstName, email)
from t
order by 1
```

The `1` in the `order by` clause means the first column in the select list.

A `case` expression is not indexable while the coalesce function is

```
create index t_index on t (coalesce(lastName || ' ' || firstName, email));
```

Comment: Is there any way to join two string in to one? Finally I have columns firstName and lastName and I need to check both. But when I use concat() there is no separator. When I use two concats(), the separator(" ") is not NULL.

Answer (score 2):

What means "not set name"? Is it `NULL` or `'---'`? However, you can use `CASE`:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN Name IS NULL THEN Email ELSE Name END AS User
FROM 
    dbo.TableName
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN Name IS NULL THEN Email ELSE Name END ASC, Email ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT MyName = CASE 
        WHEN NAME = '---'
            THEN Email
        ELSE NAME
        END
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY CASE 
        WHEN NAME = '---'
            THEN Email
        ELSE NAME
        END ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and fast:

```
select name as output from tablename where name is not null
union
select email as output from tablename where name is null
order by output asc
```